# Sequelize Join with Count of matching id

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two models, Post and PostLikes, where PostLikes.postId references Post.id. I am trying to run Post.findAll({}) where PostLike.postId = Post.id. I have tried many, many things and have been unable to get anywhere. Here is what I tried last, which shows all of the info from Post, but LikeCount is 0.

```
await Post.findAll({
    attributes: [
      "id",
      "username",
      "title",
      "body",
      "createdAt",
      "updatedAt",
      [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("PostLikes.postId")), "LikeCount"]
    ],
    include: [
      {
        model: PostLike,
        attributes: []
      }
    ],
    group: ["Post.id"]
})
```

Edit: As requested, here are my model defs.

Post:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define(
    "Post",
    {
      title: DataTypes.STRING,
      body: DataTypes.TEXT,
      userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      username: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {}
  );
  Post.associate = function(models) {
    Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "username",
      onDelete: "cascade"
    });
    Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "userId",
      onDelete: "cascade"
    });
    Post.hasMany(models.Comment, { foreignKey: "id" });
    Post.hasMany(models.PostLike, { foreignKey: "id" });
  };
  return Post;
};
```

PostLike:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const PostLike = sequelize.define(
    "PostLike",
    {
      liked: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      postId: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    {}
  );
  PostLike.associate = function(models) {
    PostLike.belongsTo(models.Post, {
      foreignKey: "postId",
      onDelete: "cascade"
    });
    PostLike.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "userId",
      onDelete: "cascade"
    });
  };
  return PostLike;
};
```

Comment: Can you show your model definitions? I tested it and it works for me(at least with the way i set up the models)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there seems to be something wrong with this setup, i never setup my associations this way(sequelize is very confusing and the docs seem to be inconsistent with their examples), so it's hard to tell. But i've played with your models, and i was getting some constraint error, when i was trying to add more than one PostLike. I changed it a bit, and got it to work( i removed the user references, being that they are irrelevant for the problem here):

```
  module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
        const Post = sequelize.define(
            "Post",
            {
                title: DataTypes.STRING,
                body: DataTypes.TEXT,
                userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                username: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            {}
        );
        Post.associate = function (models) {


            Post.hasMany(models.PostLike);
        };


        return Post;
    };



  module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const PostLike = sequelize.define(
        "PostLike",
        {
          liked: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
          userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,         
        },
        {}
      );
      PostLike.associate = function(models) {//
        PostLike.belongsTo(models.Post);        
      }; 

    return PostLike;
  };
```

After inserting one post, and two postLikes, this is the result:
[image]

Comment: Interesting. So after you modified the models, you used the same query in the description and it worked? You're right, sequelize is not consistent with their documentation, which is why I think there might be more wrong, because after making the changes you did I'm still having problems.

Comment: Well, it works for now..but i think this isn't the good way to set up associations. i don't use the "associate" function at all

Comment: This did work. Thank you so much. I noticed a lot of people saying there are issues with sequelize and it capitalizing the first letter of a column name when querying. I went through my project and capitalized all the first letters in my migrations, models and queries and what you provided worked like a charm. Thanks again!